# Through what channels does China communicate with business people like Elon Musk?

Tags: china

https://www.cnbc.com/2023/02/28/chinas-ccp-warns-elon-musk-against-sharing-wuhan-lab-leak-report.html

> Chinese state-run media warned Tesla CEO Elon Musk that he was risking
> his relationship with China after he retweeted about the U.S.
> government’s “low-confidence” assessment that the Covid pandemic
> originated in a Wuhan laboratory.

Here, in this case, China decided to use state-run media to communicate with Elon Musk, but I am wondering if it may use diplomats? If they won't use diplomats, what kind of people China sends to be able to talk or send some message to a business person or private person like Elon Musk. Is there any official channel through which China can easily communicate with? What are the protocols and do you need some kind of permission?

Comment: You do know that Musk has factories and many other facilities in China? They could easily be used to pass on a message formally and informally. In China, as in any other country, local businesspeople and executives will meet political figures both formally and informally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If China want to contact Elon Musk, they won't do it in one way. They would do everyway possible. Be it email, social media or start making an appointment in spaceX headquarter. Their protocol is every possible way.

Though consider the possibility of spam email, most of time the only way chinese government can contact Elon Musk successfully is physically appointment. i.e. Elon Musk attend a Chinese hold meeting or vice versa.